# Google App Engine update not showing updated version

Tags: google-app-engine

When I update a new version to Google App Engine, the new version does not show on the AppSpot domain, but it does show on the version domain like v2.appspot.com. Does anyone know how to make the latest version update live?

This is the command I am using to do updates:

```
appcfg.py update .
```

This is the output of my terminal command prompt:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Air:crm Mike$ appcfg.py update .
08:38 PM Application: telipayments; version: crm2
08:38 PM Host: appengine.google.com
08:38 PM 
Starting update of app: telipayments, version: crm2
08:38 PM Getting current resource limits.
08:38 PM Scanning files on local disk.
08:38 PM Scanned 500 files.
08:38 PM Scanned 1000 files.
08:38 PM Cloning 798 static files.
08:38 PM Cloning 1286 application files.
08:38 PM Compilation starting.
08:38 PM Compilation completed.
08:38 PM Starting deployment.
08:38 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:38 PM Deployment successful.
08:38 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
08:38 PM Completed update of app: telipayments, version: crm2
08:38 PM Uploading cron entries.
Michaels-MacBook-Air:crm Mike$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the default version:

> appcfg.py [options] set_default_version
>
> Sets the default (serving) version of the app. By default, the serving
>   version is set to the version specified in app.yaml, unless you
>   specify another with the --version option.

Comment: I have tried that, but I get an error. Michaels-MacBook-Air:crm Mike$ appcfg.py [options] set_default_version .
Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>
appcfg.py: error: Unknown action: '[options]', is there something I need to change?

Comment: I figured it out, it worked without [options], thanks